# How to do web communication between unity player and browser with facebook-unity integration?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-canvas, facebook-unity-sdk

With the Facebook Unity SDK, how do I get access to the unity player object, so that I can call `UnityObject.SendMessage()` from the browser to the unity player? Similar to the section described here: [Calling Unity web player content functions from the web page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html).

The problem is that the facebook integration bypasses the HTML page that creates the `UnityObject2`, and hence I have no way of geting a hold of the unity player object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the javascript UnityObject2 like this:
`Application.ExternalEval("u.getUnity()....);`

That will get a hold of the unity player object.